# min-height not working in any browser

Tags: html, css

I have a main wrapper `<div>` (id `#main`) that I want to grow as text copy is added to the content `<div>`, but for some reason the main div will not grow to accommodate the other `<div>` elements that are in it let alone any content added to the content div.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kkj22/)

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a few things here: Float the parent div to the left. If this doesn't do anything then use the `overflow: hidden;` property in the parent div. Add `clear: both;` in a child element within it's container.

Comment: ok but why is overflow hidden working? it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Because it forces it to recalculate the height. Glad my answer helped you. Also, Jimmmy's solution would do nothing.

Comment: overflow hidden clears your floats.  The reason it's not working is because all of your inner divs are floated.  When an element is flaoted, it needs to be cleared.  Whether that's with overflow, or pseudo class, or even an empty div afterwards, etc..

Comment: thanks tom & zen. i dont know why but programming(js,java,as3, etc...) seems way easier to me than css. go figure :-/

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, try `#main{height:auto}`. You may need to add this same attribute to the Content DIV.